# Rewriting Specific to more General

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I'd like to do a `mod_rewrite` so that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Any requests to `users/` goes to `index.php?login=(whatever)`.

```
RewriteRule ^users/(.+) ?login=$1 [NE,L]
```

Any other requests, outside of `users/`, goes to the same place.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) users/?login=$1 [NE,L]
```

but the second part is producing a 500 Internal Server Error

I was asked to explain it, so here are some examples:

- if "domain.com/aaa/" exists, it goes to "domain.com/aaa/"
- if "domain.com/bbb/" does not exist, it goes to "domain.com/users/?login=bbb"
- if "domain.com/ccc.html exists, it goes to "domain.com/ccc.html"
- if "domain.com/ddd.html does not exist, it goes to "domain.com/users/?login=ddd.html"
- meanwhile, "domain.com/users/eee" goes to "domain.com/users/?login=eee" since that's the primary condition, and the second condition is a fallback or more general catchall.

Comment: The second part is not clear what you're trying to achieve, what do you mean by "any other requests, outside of users/, goes to the same place"? Same as what? Your other one goes to `/index.php` but this goes to `/users/`?

Comment: * technically, example 4 should go to: "domain.com/users/?login=ddd.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You have to repeat the conditions, they don't carry over to the next rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^users/(.+)$ /users/?login=$1 [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /users/?login=$1 [NE,L]
```

Assuming that the `/users/` directory does actually exist.

Or this is more efficient, if you're not running any rules later. It prevents any processing of existing items and avoids doubling up the file-system checks.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^users/(.+)$ /users/?login=$1 [NE,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /users/?login=$1 [NE,L]
```

Comment: It just says "if the conditions passed then stop processing here and don't change anything".

Comment: ... otherwise, observe the next two rules, whichever applies first?

Comment: Essentially, yes. If the first one of them matches then it stops processing and the second one never runs (because it then exists and hits the above directory check when the next iteration occurs).

Comment: and in my case (the question asked), it never hit a last rule, therefore never stopping (500) ?

Comment: In your case, I think the last rule was looping because it kept running each time with no check to stop it until the loop limit was reached. Really need to check the error log to be sure though.